# Prove that if a $\neq$ 0 and a*b=a*d then b=d

Tags: proof-writing, real-numbers

This problem assumes that *a, b, d* $\in$ $\mathbb R$ with a $\neq$ 0.  I've been trying to figure this out for a few days and I'm not even sure if I'm headed in the right direction with what I have so far.  I'll be justifying stuff like I did on paper, [here's a list of them](https://drive.google.com/file/d/142vQwYbLUaICXInu_c-euzJ5vl12kXN4/view?usp=sharing).

Here's what I have:

*a* = *a* $\cdot$ 1 (by Axiom 4.2 #7)

*a* = (*b* $\cdot$ $\frac 1b$) $\cdot$ *a* (by Axiom 4.2 #8)

*a* = $\frac 1b$ $\cdot$ *b* $\cdot$ *a* (by Axiom 4.2 #6)

*a* = $\frac 1d$ $\cdot$ *b* $\cdot$ *a* (our hypothesis)

So I'm not sure how to get the *d* to the other side, because there's no "justification" for just multiplying both sides by *d*.  Unless I'm overthinking it, I honestly have no idea...

Thanks in advance and if anything is unclear just let me know.

EDIT: I made a typo in the title.  I said ab-ad, but I meant ab=ad.  Sorry about that

Comment: The justification is that the LHS and the RHS of the equal sign are the same thing.  Whatever you do to it, is being done to it.  You can drop kick it and blow you nose with the LHS and that will be the same thing as drop kicking and blowing your nose with the RHS because the LHS and the RHS are the same thing.

Comment: That said not sure why you are going from $a\ne 1$ rather than $ab - ad = 0$.... $(ab-ad) = 0 \implies (ab-ad)+ad= 0+ad\implies ab+(-ad + ad) = ad\implies ab+0 =ad \implies ab=ad\implies \frac 1a(ab) = \frac 1a(ad)\implies(\frac 1aa)b=(\frac 1aa)d\implies 1*b=1d\implies b=d$.

Comment: "$a = \frac 1d ⋅ b ⋅ a$ (our hypothesis)"  I thought your hypothesis as $ab-ad =0$.  that $b=d$ is your *conclusion*.  And even then you must state that if $b = d$ then $\frac 1b = \frac 1d$ (via the theorem that inverses are unique).

Comment: @fleablood you're right, I miswrote the title, I meant if ab=ad, not ab-ad.

Answer (score 1):

To provide a perhaps simpler and more 'constructive' approach to this older question, let's view this as a simplification problem:$%
\require{begingroup}
\begingroup
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\Ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\then}{\Rightarrow}
\newcommand{\when}{\Leftarrow}
%$ Assuming $\;a \not= 0\;$, simplify $\;a \cdot b = a \cdot d\;$ to $\;b = d\;$.  And let's see if we can use only the axioms, not the theorems already given.

So which axioms allow us to go from $\;a \cdot z\;$ to $\;z\;$?  Your cheat sheet gives us only

> **Axiom 4.2**: *let $\;a, b, c \in \mathbb R\;$.*
>
> [snip]
>
> *6. $\;(a \cdot b) \cdot c = a \cdot (b \cdot c)\;$ (associativity of multiplication)*
>
> *7. There is a real number, called $\;1\;$, with the properties that $\;1 \not= 0\;$ and $\;1\cdot a = a \cdot 1 = a\;$.*
>
> *8. If $\;a \not= 0\;$, there is an element called $\;\tfrac 1 a\;$ with the property that $\;a \cdot \tfrac 1 a = \tfrac 1 a \cdot a = 1\;$.*

Those give us $\;\tfrac 1 a \cdot a \cdot z = 1 \cdot z = z\;$  (where we can leave out the parentheses because of Axiom 4.2 #6, the associativity of $\;\cdot\;$).  In other words, to simplify $\;a\cdot \ldots\;$, we should try multiplying on the left by $\;\tfrac 1 a\;$.

So that gives us, for any $\;a,b,d \in \mathbb R\;$,

$$\calc
    a \cdot b = a \cdot d
\op\then\hints{Leibniz' rule, i.e., replacing equals by equals,}
        \hint{allowed because $\;a \not= 0\;$}
    \tfrac 1 a \cdot (a \cdot b) = \tfrac 1 a \cdot (a \cdot d)
\op\equiv\hint{Axiom 4.2 #6, i.e., $\;\cdot\;$ is associative, twice}
    (\tfrac 1 a \cdot a) \cdot b = (\tfrac 1 a \cdot a) \cdot d
\op\equiv\hints{Axiom 4.2 #8, i.e., inverse of $\;\cdot\;$, twice,}
         \hint{allowed because $\;a \not= 0\;$}
    1 \cdot b = 1 \cdot d
\op\equiv\hint{Axiom 4.2 #7, i.e., identity of $\;\cdot\;$, twice}
    b = d
\endcalc$$
which completes the proof.

$%
\endgroup
%$

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Since you need to show $b=d$, start with $b$, and try to end up with $d$. So:

$b = 1 \cdot b  = (\frac{1}{a} \cdot a) \cdot b= \frac{1}{a} \cdot (a \cdot b)= [\text{... for you to work out ...}] = d$

Answer (score 0):

The cheat sheet is taking it as obvious, but maybe should have written that

A) Addition and multiplication are binary operations. so that if $a,b\in \mathbb R$ then $a+b\in \mathbb R$ and $a*b\in \mathbb R$... and these values are consistent, $1+3$ will always equal $4$; they won't one day wake up and decide they want to equal  $\sqrt \pi$.

B) "$=$" is a statement of identity.  If $pinkybooboo = honeypotchickenpie$, then $pinkybooboo$ and $honeypotchickenpie$ are the same thing.  So as $pinkybooboo + 19$ is a real number and $honeypotchickenpie + 19$ is a real number, they are both the same number. That is because you are doing the same binary operation between the *SAME* two numbers. (That is between whatever number  $pinkybooboo$ and $honeypotchickenpie$ is, and whatever number "$19$" is.)

So

$ab - ad = 0$ (given)

$(ab-ad)+ ad = 0 + ad$ (consistency of binary operations)

$(ab-ad) + ad = ad$ (natural of additive identity)

$(ab + (-ad)) + ad = ad$ (notation of adding additive inverse)

$ab + (-ad + ad) = ad$ (associativity)

$ab + 0 = ad$ (nature of additive inverse)

$ab = ad$ (nature of additive identity)

$\frac 1a$ exists and is unique.  (axiom 4.2.8 and the theorem)

$\frac 1a(ab) = \frac 1a(ad)$ (consistency of binary operations)

$(\frac 1aa)b = (\frac 1aa)d$ (associativity)

$1*b = 1*d$ (nature of multiplicative inverses)

$b = d$ (nature of multiplicative identity)